# How do I retrieve public key from private key in database

Tags: c#, aes, rsa

I am creating a pair of RSA keys. I store the public key in the database and the private key in a file (encrypted). I use the public key to encrypt the working key. The working key in turn encrypts column data in the database. In the database, I have a table that stores a list of working keys and their corresponding public keys. When a user wants to view some information from a table, he will have to provide the private key which the app will use to decrypt the corresponding public key, and hence decrypt the information. But, how can I find the corresponding public key from the private key? I have been searching in the forum, but I cannot find the information I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can access the modulus of the public key and the private key then you can simply perform a compare of the two (big) integers. Both keys require the modulus, and the modulus is always identical for the public key and private key.

On cryptographic devices and in key databases normally an ID is stored with the keys. This key is usually (part of) a cryptographic hash over the modulus.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I just tried it by using RSAParameters publicKey = rsa.ExportParameters(false); string publicKeyModulus = Convert.ToBase64String(publicKey.Modulus); and the same for the private key. Both have the same modulus.

Comment: Note that although the modulus *should* be unique to the key pair, it is usually a good idea to check this in advance and reject the key pair if the modulus is known. This could e.g. protect you if the random number generator that was used during key pair generation is broken.